# Ubuntu 11.10 Wellcomm mobile broadband

Tags: 11.10, internet, connection

I'm using Ubuntu 11.10 on Acer 3620 but unable to connect the Internet. It disconnects everytime.

The Wellcomm specs are as follows:

- Interface type : USB 2.0 high speed
- Proocol        : HSDPA/UMTS/EDGE/GPRS/GSM
- Frequency      : HSDPA/UMTS  2100 Mhz Edge/Gprs/Gsm 1900/1800/900/850Mhz
- Transmision    : HSDPA 3.6 Mbps DL
- Max data rate  : UMTS 384Kbps UL
- System Required: Windows XP, Vista/7, Linux, Mac

With Windows XP no problems

Any suggestions?

Regards,

Budi M

Answer (score 1):

Try wvdial:

`sudo apt-get install wvdial` to install via the terminal

or install it using the Software Center:

[image: Install via the software center]